# What does it mean by active quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

Do the active quarks mean valence quarks? Or we can also consider other quarks, like when there are offshell-quarks produced from gluons by pair production processes?

[For example](https://slideplayer.com/slide/14648174/): how the active quark is different than the other valence quarks?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, the usual meaning of active quark is quarks whose rest mass is lower than the energy scale of the environment. So for example, the active quarks of $T = 0$ QCD are $u,d,s$ because they all have rest mass lower than the QCD scale, $\Lambda_\text{QCD}\approx 200\text{ MeV}$.

In response to your updated question, active quarks are on shell. Basically, you pair up all quarks into diquark quasiparticles, and then any unpaired quarks are the active quarks. Since quarks are identical particles, the specific one you choose to be "active" is arbitrary, but it will necessarily be of a fixed flavour.

Comment: How about the proton where we have three valence quarks, and there are a lot of sea-quarks that generated from the gluons pair productions. Which quark would be the active quark in this case?

Comment: Since all the sea-quarks must carry the quantum numbers of the vacuum, each of them can be paired up, so the active quark is unchanged.